# Virtual ground in non inverting op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, virtual-ground

Why is the voltage not equal in inverting and non-inverting terminals in a non-inverting opamp?  During the derivation, we take two different V1 and V2.  Why doesn't virtual ground apply here?

Comment: In a non-inverting opamp also, the virtual ground applies. Can you add a diagram showing the non-inverting opamp and the source which told you that virtual ground does not apply here

Comment: In a non-inverting configuration, V1 and V2 are virtually the same, but neither one is anywhere near "ground", so "virtual ground" can't be used when analyzing the rest of the circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both of the circuits below, \$V_Q = V_P\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flYZJC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the left circuit (inverting) one of the inputs, P, is held explicitly at ground, 0V, but the other Q is maintained at the *same potential* by the op-amp with negative feedback, so \$V_Q = V_P = 0V\$. Hence the name "virtual ground" for node Q.

On the right (non-inverting), P and Q also have the same potential, for the same reasons, but because neither of them are connected to ground, we don't call node Q a virtual ground. In this case \$V_Q = V_P = V_{IN}\$.

Comment: But Vq=Vout*(R4/(R3+R4)).why will it become equal to Vp or Vin.why can't Vp become equal to Vq=Vout*(R4/(R3+R4)).

Comment: @cvcv, that's correct, but there is negative feedback, which means the op-amp adjusts \$V_{OUT}\$ to exactly the potential necessary to achieve \$V_{OUT}\frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4}=V_{IN}\$. In the same way you use negative feedback to adjust steering wheel position, such that your car's actual direction of travel and your desired direction are always exactly equal.

Comment: @cvcv On the right (non-inverting), only *you* are in control of \$V_{IN}\$ (and consequently \$V_P\$). But the op-amp is in control of \$V_{OUT}\$ and \$V_Q\$. \$V_P\$ doesn't budge from whatever you set it to, and the op-amp adjusts \$V_{OUT}\$ to achieve \$V_Q=V_P\$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubt.I now understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

> *Why is the voltage not equal in inverting and non inverting terminal
> in non inverting op amp*

**It is** precisely equal for an ideal op-amp in a non-inverting circuit (just as it is in an inverting op-amp circuit). The massive open loop gain means that for any reasonable output voltage level, the difference in input pin voltages has to be very small (ideally zero).

Just consider a real op-amp with an open-loop gain of 1 million. If the output voltage is a few volts then, the voltage difference of the two input pins has to be a few microvolts. A few microvolts for most applications is trivial and many times less than other op-amp errors. Hence, why we say the voltages are equal.

> *During the derivation, we take two different V1 and V2.*

Yes, we start off assuming that the two voltages are different and, we end up proving that V1 largely equals V2.

> *Why doesn't virtual ground apply here?*

Strictly speaking it isn't a virtual ground. Well, put it another way, for an inverting op-amp circuit, the non-inverting input is grounded hence we have a virtual ground on the inverting input but, for a non-inverting op-amp circuit, the inverting input "follows" the non-inverting input and, through laziness (for want of a better word), we still call it a virtual ground.

Comment: I have been known to call it a virtual input:)